# Python Pandas SQLAlchemy how to make connection to a local SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to a local network SQL Server using SQLAlchemy. I don't know how to use SQLAlchemy for doing this. Other examples I have seen do not use the more modern Python (3.6+) f-string. I need to have data in a Pandas dataframe "df". I'm not 100% sure but this local server does not have a username and password requirement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is working right now.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 
import sqlalchemy as sql

server = 'NetworkServer' # this is the server name that IT said my data is on.
database = 'Database_name' # The name of the database and this database has multiple tables.
table_name = 't_lake_data' # name of the table that I want.

# I'm not sure but this local server does not have a username and password requirement. 

engine = sql.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server')

# I don't know all the column names so I use * to represent all column names. 
sql_str = f"SELECT * FROM dbo.{table_name}"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_str, engine, parse_dates="DATE_TIME")
```

So if there are concerns with how this looks leave a comment. Thank you.